# How to use a simple data class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to `Kotlin` and learning it, I am having a simple data class

```
data class Country{

    @SerializedName("name")
    val countryName: String?,
    @SerializedName("capital")
    val capital: String?,
    @SerializedName("flagPNG")
    val flag: String?

}
```

**Errors I am facing**:

[image]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data class should look like this:

```
data class Country(

    @SerializedName("name")
    val countryName: String?,
    @SerializedName("capital")
    val capital: String?,
    @SerializedName("flagPNG")
    val flag: String?

)
```

The difference is, like mentioned in the comments: I used normal parentheses around the fields while you used curly braces

Comment: it is working but, what is the difference  ... both look the same .... waht mistake i made ?

Comment: Data classes must have a primary constructor and that primary constructor needs to have at least one parameter!

Comment: @Devrath look at how the answer uses normal parentheses around the fields while you used curly braces. Hard to notice at first.

Comment: Why it should have at least one parameter?

Answer (score 1):

**Data Class** in **Kotiln** must have a *variable/value parameter* in it's constructor declaration.

**Official doc states that :**

> To ensure consistency and meaningful behavior of the generated code,
>   **data classes** have to fulfill the following requirements:
>
> 1. The primary constructor needs to have at least one parameter;
> 2. All primary constructor parameters need to be marked as **val** or **var**;
> 3. Data classes cannot be **abstract, open, sealed** or **inner**;
> 4. *(before 1.1)* Data classes may only **implement interfaces**.

So, your data class should be something similar like below :

```
data class Foo(
    val bar: Any
)
```

**Note:** In Kotlin, you can declare class constructor just by placing '()' following by class name to make it as primary constructor.

You class declaration should be something like below :

```
data class Country(
    @SerializedName("name")
    val countryName: String?,
    @SerializedName("capital")
    val capital: String?,
    @SerializedName("flagPNG")
    val flag: String?
)
```

Refer [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) for more info.